# Firebase java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzcnu
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

How can I fix this error? Please help me. It took me so long to fix it and try and try other solution I found but unluckily my problem doesn't solve.

[App Gradle Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Vpg.png)

Comment: Use same version of every support library. Try to resolve the red lines in your gradle file.

Comment: try with new version " compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'"

Comment: Holy Moly!! Thanks to you my friend. I'm about to cry . You save me! Lots of thank you for you @mudisten

Comment: I already try that @vivek but it says that I have duplicate class and Multidex files define something like that, but anyway thank also to you

Comment: For multidex Either you have add jar via gradle and add jar manually if that not solve try   packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }  in app build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same version of all the dependencies of Firebase for it to be compatible. You are using version 9 here whereas other dependency of Firebase are using 10. You need to make sure you use the same version for all. You can always check the docs of Firebase for the latest version.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/?authuser=1